# Join nested dataframes Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframes:

Dataframe1:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id  |records                                                           |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|473 |[{1, 8414932001257, 34301, 70.0}, {2, 015878529935, 34301, 140.0}]|
|1529|[{1, 54490802, 34301, 70.0}]                                      |
|2052|[{1, 016229901172, 34301, 70.0}, {1, 8410793206138, 34304, 40.0}] |
|894 |[{1, 8429359001223, 34301, 70.0}]                                 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|2053|[{1, 8480012007242, 34304, 40.0}, {1, 8420030011050, 34301, 70.0}]|
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Whose schema is:

```
StructType(
    StructField(id,LongType,true), 
    StructField(records,ArrayType(
        StructType(
            StructField(count,LongType,true), 
            StructField(barcode,StringType,true), 
            StructField(height,LongType,true), 
            StructField(weight,DoubleType,true)),
        true),
    true)
)
```

Dataframe2:

```
+------------+--------+
|     barcode|itemType|
+------------+--------+
|015878529935|Box     |
|015878539989|Box     |
|016229901141|Can     |
|016229901172|Box     |
|016229901189|Can     |
+------------+--------+
```

Whose schema is:

```
StructType(
    StructField(barcode,StringType,true), 
    StructField(itemType,StringType,true)
)
```

I would like to join the two dataframes by `barcode` in such a way that `Dataframe1` has the `itemType` column of `Dataframe2`, so I would have a schema like:

```
StructType(
    StructField(id,LongType,true), 
    StructField(records,ArrayType(
        StructType(
            StructField(count,LongType,true), 
            StructField(barcode,StringType,true), 
            StructField(material,LongType,true), 
            StructField(weight,DoubleType,true)),
            StructField(itemType,StringType,true)),
        true),
    true)
)
```

I have tried the following code:

```
dataframe1.join(dataframe2, dataframe1("records.barcode") === dataframe2("barcode"), "leftouter")

Result:
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(spark_catalog.database.table1.`records`.`barcode` = spark_catalog.database.table2.`barcode`)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(spark_catalog.database.table1.`records`.`barcode` = spark_catalog.database.table2.`barcode`)' (array<string> and string).;
```

But logically it fails because the records column is an Array of `StructType` and `barcode` is a `StringType`. My problem is that I don't know how to access the `records.barcode` level of each element of the Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is very good.. you just have to make small change in your code to work as expected.

```
dataframe1
.withColumn("records", explode_outer($"records")) 
// small change you have to make here.. because records is an array column .. to access barcode you have to explode array then join with other data frame
.join(
     dataframe2, 
     dataframe1("records.barcode") === dataframe2("barcode"), 
    "leftouter"
)
```